# New line by enter key in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started using Android Studio.
When I was editing "activity_main.xml", I cannot go to new line by pressing Enter key. Also, I tried to insert new letter, but new letter was just replaced. So I clicked everywhere to make enter key work then suddenly I got new line. I do not know why.

It was so annoying. Did I press a wrong key? I do not want this to happen again.

I searched "new line enter key android studio" to know about this, but I could not find anything helpful.

Comment: please reply if you've found a solution to make a new line by default, without pressing Insert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you accidentally press the `Insert` key on your keyboard? Try pressing it again to see if that helps.

Comment: how can this be changed? I want Enter to make new line by default

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer this is the default behavior in Android Studio, pressing `Enter` inside the XML designer will result in a CRLF. If this is not the case for you check out [Keyboard Commands, Android Studio Tips and Tricks](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html) which may have some useful info for you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, it was because I changed a keymap shortcut recently and validated the form by pressing `Enter` key.

But it did not noticed that instead of validate the form it **changed the shortcut** !

1. Go to menu *File* > *Settings...* > *Keymap*
2. Verify which action is assigned with key `Enter` and remove it
3. Find action `New Line` and add it a new shortcut (return key)
4. Validate

Comment: The default action is called "Enter" instead of "New Line". "Start New Line" is the wrong one, it will not insert `\n` without going to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

Go to menu File > Settings > Editor > Appearance
then Uncheck "use block caret"

Comment: Thanks, after lost of search finally your answer work for me.