# Android Studio Enter key not making new line

Tags: android-studio

I don't know if I have changed something, but I can't make a new line when pressing `Enter`, it just goes to the next line. To insert a new line, I have to press `Insert` first....
How can I change that?

Comment: Make sure it isn't set to 'replace' instead of 'insert'

Comment: what to be set to "replace"?

Answer (score 13):

Press **insert** on your keyboard, That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Is it the "Insert" key"?

There is a similar thread. Check if this
[New line by enter key in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057345/new-line-by-enter-key-in-android-studio)

solves your problem